# How can i execute cloudformation changesets in ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cloudformation

I am using ansible in cloudformation

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/cloudformation_module.html

But i could not find any way how to execute changesets using ansible

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to use the AWS CLI in an ansible `command`.

Something like:

```
- name: Execute a specific changeset
  command: aws cloudformation execute-change-set --change-set-name arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:changeSet/SampleChangeSet/1a2345b6-0000-00a0-a123-00abc0abc000
```

Note that you would need to set the AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY appropriately.

Also keep in mind the following, from the [CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets-execute.html):

> After you execute a change set, AWS CloudFormation deletes all change
>   sets that are associated with the stack because they aren't valid for
>   the updated stack. If an update fails, you need to create a new change
>   set.

So you may find it more helpful to create a CloudFormation stack via ansible, rather than create a changeset somewhere that would just be run once from ansible and subsequently deleted.

Comment: Thanks , i will be creating change sets in ansible only and in next coomand execute it , so that in the console i can see the chnagets

Comment: No problem! In that case, you'll probably create the changeset in one command, get the ARN and assign it to an environment variable in a second command, and execute the changeset with the env variable ARN in the third command.

And don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if you found it helpful. :)